# How to make collision in scenekit

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit

i am trying to make collision of two objects, but "func physicsWorld(world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBeginContact contact: SCNPhysicsContact)" is not being called.

my code is,

```
    let carbonNode = SCNNode(geometry: carbonAtom())
    carbonNode.position = SCNVector3Make(-6, 8, 0)        

    let coneAtomNode = SCNNode(geometry: coneAtom())
    pinNode = coneAtomNode

    pinNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.dynamicBody()
    pinNode.physicsBody?.restitution = 0.9;
    pinNode.categoryBitMask = 0x4;
    pinNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ~(0x4);

    coneAtomNode.position = SCNVector3Make(-6, -15, 0)
    scene.rootNode.addChildNode(coneAtomNode)

    balloonNode = carbonNode

    sceneView.scene = scene
    sceneView.scene?.physicsWorld.contactDelegate = self

     pinNode.runAction(SCNAction.repeatAction(SCNAction.moveTo(SCNVector3Make(-6, 10+5, 0), duration: 1.5), count: 1), completionHandler: {

    })
```

Comment: Please refer to this http://www.raywenderlich.com/83748/beginning-scene-kit-tutorial

Comment: thanks vaibhav, but this tutorial does't teach about collision (contact of two objects)

Comment: Need to set pinNode.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = 0x4 (missing the physicsBody)

Answer (score 3):

You can't move "dynamic" bodies programmatically (i.e no action, no animation and no manual updates of position/rotation/scale). You can either move dynamic bodies with forces or use a kinematicBody instead.
Kinematic bodies behave just like static bodies but you can move them programmatically.

Also if you want to get physics contacts between two nodes, the two nodes need to have a physicsBody.

Comment: didBeginContact is not called, even it doesn't have dynamic body.

Comment: do your two nodes have a physicsBody?

Comment: specifically, a physicsBody that is dynamic and ideally (for now) the collision categories, masks all left at their default values

Comment: i just set physics body as static. pinNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody.staticBody(), but it's not collided.